# Over an alphabet of $n$ symbols, how many are the strings of length $k$ without consecutive symbols repeated?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

From combinatorics, it's known that over an alphabet of $n$ symbols there are $n^k$ different strings of length $k$, of which $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ (assuming $k \le n$) are those without any repeated symbols.

But how to find how many strings of length $k$ without **consecutive** symbols repeated?

For example if the alphabet is {*A*, *B*, *C* }, acceptable strings are *ABAB* and *BACA*, whereas *ABBA* or *AAAA* are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: You have $n$ choices for the first symbol. After that, you always have $n-1$ choices.

Comment: ...which means there are $n*(n-1)^{(k-1)}$ possible strings of length $k$ without consecutive symbols repeated over an alphabet of $n$ symbols.

Comment: @Claudio Floreani: Yes, that's right. I wanted to leave you something to do!